# How to model and define a fact that can have multiple values for a dimension in an ssas cube

Tags: ssas, dimensional-modeling

I am encountering an issue in which I have sales which can be part of multiple promotions.  I am trying to use a sales fact table which will have multiple rows for sales in multiple promotions.  Thus, the cube can only accurately be used to aggregate sales within a promotion, not across promotions.

e.g., here are a couple of rows that could appear in the fact table:

```
saleid   sku   sales_date   promotion_id    revenue
  1      123     1-1-2013      1             10
  1      123     1-1-2013      2             10
```

This is one sale which gave the company revenue of $10, but it was part of two different promotions.  I want to give users the ability to sum sales for promotion 1, and sales for promotion 2, but not for all promotions at the same time (which would indicate $20 of sales overall).

I think that this should be able to be done in SSAS, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Ideally the cube would be defined so that the user can only use it in conjunction with the promotion dimension (and other dimensions as desired), but I'd settle for defining the facts so that they cannot be summed across promotions.

thanks,  --sw